# No suitable driver found when exporting to a JAR-file?

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql, jdbc, jar

I am trying to get my project into a JAR so I can run it as a CLI.
I have two JDBC connectors that I am using, one for MySQL one for PostgreSQL. Both are located in the same directory and work fine if I run them in the IDE.
When I create the JAR the MySQL connector still works fine, however when trying to establish a connection to PostgreSQL the following error appears.
[image: Terminal output when running my jar]
What really irritates me is that the connector seems to be included in the build of the jar.
[image]
Both the MySQL connector and PostgreSQL connector are listed in the build.
How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that all JDBC-4-compliant JDBC drivers contain a file `/META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` that lists the `java.sql.Driver` implementations in the JAR files. This is used by the `java.sql.DriverManager` to load the available JDBC drivers.

The process you used for merging apparently doesn't merge the different files from the drivers into a single file, so it only has the content of one of the drivers. As a result, the other driver isn't loaded automatically.

Possible solutions:

1. Don't merge JAR files into a single JAR, but instead use the `Class-Path` attribute of `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` to specify the JARs you use, and execute your program with `java -jar your.jar`
2. Make sure `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` is merged correctly (or maybe provide your own), depending on how you merge, there might be an option to configure which files need to be merged
3. Explicitly load the drivers using `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")` and `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver")` (do it for both to prevent problems if order of merging files changes, and the other file wins)

Comment: Thank you. Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver"); actually made the trick.

Comment: @ChristianKammerer Yes, but as I mention, I recommend to load both drivers explicitly, in case a future merge uses a different order and the PostgreSQL version of `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` wins instead of the MySQL version.

Comment: I am not sure I comprehend completely, but is this a race condition of which driver gets loaded in? I put both of them in for good measure, ;)

Comment: @ChristianKammerer No, this is about you creating a single JAR with the contents of multiple JARs, and the way you are merging those JARs doesn't merge the content of the `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` files that exists in both the MySQL Connector/J JAR and the PostgreSQL JDBC JAR. Instead, it picks only the content of one file (in this case, the one from MySQL Connector/J). So, when `DriverManager` discovers the available JDBC drivers, it finds one service definition file, that only lists the MySQL Connector/J driver.